# Ionic 3 (or Ionic 2): Get JSON file content using <input type="file">

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I'm migrating an Ionic 1 app to Ionic 3 (or even Ionic 2) and I can't seem to get access to the JSON content of a file that a user selects.

I have the following element:

```
<input type="file" name="file" (change)="fileSelected($event)">
```

When I look at the event that is passed, I can get the File object using:

```
fileSelected(ev) {
  console.log('file: ', ev.target.files[0]);
  console.log('file: ', ev.srcElement.files[0]);
}
```

But I can't seem to get the content of the file (which in this case is just JSON).

Any suggestions?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
fileSelected(ev) {
  let myFile = ev.target.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(myFile);
  reader.onload = (ev) => {
    this.fileJSON = reader.result;
  }
}
```